# generate iframe from django tag

Tags: python, django, iframe

I managed to create a REST api with multiple items like this

```
{
    "title": "problem_demo.0",
    "html": "<div><iframe src=/scenario/problem_demo.0/ width=\"400\" height=\"500\"></iframe></div>",
    "description": "desc",
    "url": "/scenario/problem_demo.0/"
},
```

And i managed to extract some data and render them in my template like this

**views.py**

```
if embedserializer.is_valid():
       embed = embedserializer.validated_data
       return render(request, 'workbench/dir/xblock.html', 
       {'embed': embed})
```

**xblock.html**

```
% block content %}

<ul>
    <li>title : {{ embed.title}}</li>
    <li>description: {{ embed.description }}</li>
    <li>html : {{ embed.html }}</li>
    <li>url : {{ embed.url }}</li>

</ul>


{% endblock %}
```

What i want is to be able to get an actual iframe when i add `{{ embed.html }}` in my template and not the value of the key "html".

Answer (score 0):

You want `safe` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

```
<li>html : {{ embed.html|safe }}</li>
```