# How to use iframe in Django for Production?

Tags: python, django, iframe

I have been using WordPress since 2005 now in the process of switching all my websites to Django Projects.  This is my first Django Project which will have multiple web apps.

I am using Visual Studio Preview 2017 to create my Django Project.
In my project I setup a main web app that holds the projects urls.py, view.py, model.py and templates folder that holds the main html pages.  This main web app will connect to the other web apps within the project.

I know the objective of web app development is to keep a person on the web app.  With that said I need to add blogs and affiliate pages to my project.  The only way I know how to do this is iframe.

I found one option on this site but it did not make any sense except for adding | safe to the url.       [1]: [generate iframe from django tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432537/generate-iframe-from-django-tag)

I looked at the above link and the question I have if I need to use serializer in my code for my project web app?

My code is :

Affi web app

web_host_python.html

```
     <html>
<head><title>Web Host Python Hosting</title></head>

<body>

{{ whpaff.html | safe }}

</body>
</html>
```

whpaff.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src=" https://www.webhostpython.com/billing/aff.php?aff=69" 
                  style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="web_host_python" 
                  scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" 
                  marginwidth="0px" 
                  height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

urls_affi.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpattens = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    ]
```

view_affi.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def web_host_python(request):
    return render(request, 'affi/web_host_python.html')
```

Project Main App

url.py

```
   """
Definition of urls for affiliate_sites.
"""

from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import url
import django.contrib.auth.views

import app.forms
import app.views

# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
# from django.conf.urls import include
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^affi$', views_affi.web_host_python, name='web_host_python),
    url(r'^$', app.views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact$', app.views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^about', app.views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^login/$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.login,
        {
            'template_name': 'app/login.html',
            'authentication_form': app.forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title': 'Log in',
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            }
        },
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.logout,
        {
            'next_page': '/',
        },
        name='logout'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

view.py

```
   """
Definition of views.
"""

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime

def web_host_python(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'affi/web_host_python.html'
        {
            'title':'affi/web_host_python.html',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )

def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )

def contact(request):
    """Renders the contact page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/contact.html',
        {
            'title':'Contact',
            'message':'Your contact page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )

def about(request):
    """Renders the about page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/about.html',
        {
            'title':'About',
            'message':'Your application description page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
```

Is any of this correct what I did?

Or is there an alternative and easier way to do iframe in Django?

Thank you for all of your advice.

Marcus

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code is doing what you think. The `{{ whpaff.html | safe }}` will look for a parameter named `whpaff` to be passed into the template when the `render()` function is called, and then embed the value of the `html` attribute from that parameter into the generated output. You are passing other parameters like `title`, `message`, and `year` to some of your `render()` functions, but I don't see anywhere that you are passing a `whpaff` parameter. I think you intend for it to magically load the file "whpaff.html" and embed the contents of that file into your output, but that's not how the `{{ }}` block works in a Django template.

On the other hand, an `<iframe>` is an HTML tag that allows you to display content from some other URL in your page. Django has nothing directly to do with an `<iframe>`. You can include an `<iframe>` tag in your Django template just like any other HTML tag, or you could have an `<iframe>` tag that references a URL that is generated by Django, but Django wouldn't know or care about the `<iframe>` in either case.

Comment: I saw in the other Stackoverflow link I reference before the code it talks about using    | safe  in Django for iframe.   Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432537/generate-iframe-from-django-tag            But this was a separate part of the url.py and view.py  I also understand that iframe is a html tag but it has to communicate through Django.  Can you please look at the link above and tell me if how to do that to what I am doing.  Plus it also shows              serializer to use to with what I am trying to do.

Comment: The `safe` filter tells the Django template system not to escape any HTML code it might find in the value that is being embedded. It is used when you trust the source of the data. Otherwise Django templates assume all embedded data is a potential risk and it blocks tags and such that might be used for HTML injection attacks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056883/when-should-i-use-escape-and-safe-in-djangos-template-system

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding in the iframe tag like so into your html rather than loading the html content of the iframe. For example:

```
<body>
  <iframe src="https://www.mxysite.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

Unless maybe I'm misunderstanding part of your question?

Comment: David,

You are speaking about whpaff.html file?

And with this code will it do the whole page?

Marcus